# Role of eternal and maxElementsInMemory in ehcache?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I have below configuration in my project

```
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false" overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="false" />

<cache name="customerList" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false" overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

As per my understanding `eternal =true` attribute explains cache will never expire. But when i mention `eternal =false`, how long cache will remain active?

Also i have mentioned `maxElementsInMemory=1000`, what will happen when i have more than 1000 elements to put in cache. Will not they be stored in cache and discarded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two configuration options relate to two fundamental caching concepts:

- Data freshness / Expiry: Data in cache can expire in order to guarantee that what the cache returns does not become stale. This is controlled in Ehcache 2.x by different attributes:

  - eternal attribute - if true indicates that mappings never expire,
  - time to live (TTL) - a duration after the cache mapping was created,
  - and/or time to idle (TTI) - a duration after the cache mapping was last accessed
- Capacity control / Eviction: Limit the cache size so that you do not exhaust memory of your application by filling up a cache

  - When the maximum number of mappings is reached, the cache will start evicting entries - the exact entry evicted depends from the cache configuration / implementation
  - In Ehcache 2.x, maxElementsInMemory is a count based capacity control, there is also a memory size based option.

Comment: I understand these points. But my questions are specific. Here are these again

Comment: First question:-Say cache with name `customerList`is created at 12'O clock in above example. Now when will cache be evicted as I did not specify attribute `timeToLiveSeconds` ?

Comment: Second question is :- say I want to add one more element after 1000. I cache will evict least recently used one and stored the latest element in list as I mentioned memoryStoreEvictionPolicy. Is that right ?

Comment: To your first question: expiry and eviction are two different topics. If you do not specify expiry, elements will not expire.

Comment: Regarding eviction, you should not make strong statements about which element will be evicted. It would be way too costly (in memory or CPU) to have a pure "least recently used" behavior. One element will be evicted when you add above capacity.

Comment: Thanks for first one. About second  answer `you should not make strong statements about which element will be evicted.` I agree we should mention parameters like `timeToLiveSeconds` even with that we have to mention attributes like `memoryStoreEvictionPolicy=LRU' becoz say I want to add some element before `timeToLiveSeconds` expires, system has to do based on some algo like `LRU` or `FIFO` etc

Comment: Not sure I get your last comment. Maybe that's worth a new question. Could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

When eternal is false, you can control how long items stay in cache by using the `timeToLiveSeconds` attribute. For example, for items to expire after 1 minute:

```
<cache name="customerList" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="60" overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

If you have more than 1000 items and have specified `maxElementsInMemory=1000`, then only 1000 of them will be stored in cache. `maxElementsInMemory` is an upper limit.

Comment: First question:-Say cache with name `customerList`is created at 12'O clock in above example. Now will cache be evicted after 60 seconds i.e 12.01 .Right ?But in my case I did not specify attribute `timeToLiveSeconds`. so when it will be evicted ?

Comment: Second question is :- say I want to add one more element after 1000. I cache will evict least recently used one and stored the latest element in list as I mentioned memoryStoreEvictionPolicy. Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to answer this question. But as i have also gone through this issue so want to share my experience.

Hi @emilly, I'm answering specifically to your questions and we will use config. that is shared by @RCB.

```
<cache name="customerList" maxElementsInMemory="1000" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="60" overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

**Question 1:**

As *timeToLiveSeconds="60"* so it's the maximum time for which "customerList" data will be there in cache(L2). *Cache Eviction* is not directly related to the value of this attribute(*timeToLiveSeconds*).

e.g. If *customerList* is created on 12:00:00, it will be available till 12:00:59.

**Question 2:**
*say I want to add one more element after 1000. I cache will evict least recently used one and stored the latest element in list as I mentioned memoryStoreEvictionPolicy. Is that right ?*

yes, this is the cache(L2) eviction and it will be according to the *memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"* and in this example it will a valid operation before TTL(60 seconds).